# Gráfico xy em tempo real no app inventor utilizando o chart.js

Tags: google-charts, chartjs, gráfico, php

Sou novo na área de desenvolvimento em java, porém gostaria de saber como posso utilizar os gráficos chart.js para gerar um grafico scatter xy em tempo real com os dados de um sensor. O objetivo é plotar em x o potencial aplicado (V), e em y a corrente (A) lida. Já faço isso no app invetor, porém gostaria de adicionar o chart.js ou outro tipo de biblioteca java para tornar os dados dinâmicos e responsivo.
Agradeço pela atenção!